# Where to ask about specific component of packets

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I'm wanting to know about these hex digits found in packets that specify the "length" of the next field:

[image]

As shown, the `0b` indicates the length of the next field (`fn=Room 110`) is 11.

This can also be seen in DNS queries:

[image]

The `06` indicates the length of `google` is 6 characters, and the `02` indicates the length of `ru` is 2 characters.

I'm wanting to ask what is this called, there must be a terminology for this. I also want to know why its necessary to specify lengths this way. It can be seen in a lot of different types of packets.

I tried Network Engineering stack exchange but my question was closed due to mentioning DNS which is above the transport layer.

Comment: Unfamiliar with Network Engineering.SE's scope, but would it be on topic there if you just removed the reference to DNS?

Comment: I don't really know how to ask this question coherently without mentioning the examples. I also can't find a quick example at the moment in protocols below layer 4

Comment: I found that in DNS specifically its called "Label Length Octets", but I'm still curious where I could ask such a question

Comment: I _think_ plain old http://stackoverflow.com should be ok too.

Comment: [TLV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type%E2%80%93length%E2%80%93value)?